# Replace or Glue ceiling tape?

Tags: ceiling, tape

[image]
The rotten plywood panels supporting the shingles were replaced in 2019

Options:

1. cut ceiling tape
2. replace tape
3. glue tape back in place with an adhesive

If option 2) is chosen, I would need to know how to lookup the item at Home Depot / Lowes.

If option 3), what is the appropriate adhesive?

Which option is the best long term solution?

Answer (score 7):

1. Fix leak - drywall tape **does not fall off for no reason,** and the usual reason is that it got wet.
2. Cut tape
3. Apply joint compound ("drywall mud")
4. Embed tape (paper drywall joint tape, in the drywall supplies aisle at HD/Lowes/any actual building supply outlet or hardware store)
5. Apply joint compound ("drywall mud")
6. dry - scrape high spots
7. Apply joint compound ("drywall mud")
8. dry - scrape high spots
9. Apply joint compound ("drywall mud")
10. dry - scrape and/or sand high spots
11. prime
12. dry
13. paint
14. dry
15. paint
16. dry
17. paint

Comment: It seems we have yet another of those transpondian differences ;) Is US joint tape not self-adhesive, and is it as thick as that image would imply? That seems like a lot of repetition to do a simple scrim joint. UK version would be... Tape joint, plaster ceiling/wall, let dry, paint. [Paint twice but the rest is just once.] One of many online examples - http://www.ultimatehandyman.co.uk/how-to/plastering/scrim-tape

Comment: Mesh tape has some adhesive and is only suited to use with setting type compound (as opposed to the more convenient premix/drying type)  per official advice from the main maker of drywall here. Paper tape is non-adhesive and is set with mud. The image shows failed tape with mud attached.

Comment: @Tetsujin  It doesn't look like the tapered edges were used, just a straight butt joint so the mud would be deeper, thicker over the tape.

Comment: Step 2.1: Remove any water damaged drywall. Step 2.2: Remove any water damaged insulation above the drywall. Step 2.3: Replace with new, dry insulation and drywall.

Comment: **Step 2 :** Cut tape. Scrape and/or sand high spots, **prepping the area to accept new tape *at the same level as the old tape*** - if that's a butt joint you have to get almost all that mud off first. - RO sander or an actual DW sander, or the stick and a lot of sweat.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there was water damage by the wall. Was that fixed?

I'd cut the old tape off and replace it with new tape. The existing tape looks pretty built up and probably wouldn't stick to the ceiling if you tried to re-mud it back in place.  You'd need drywall tape and joint compound from the Home depot of Lowe's website, enter in the search bar.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The rotten plywood panels supporting the shingles were replaced in 2019 when the roof was replaced.